# Selected option is not updating with knockout

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I can't make the ImageType(name) update when the select is changed and the data has already been created (obtained from the model), only when a new element is created I can see that when I change the select the ImageType(name) is updated ), why would this happen?

I tried with change event (knockout) but without results

```js
function PatientInsuranceCarrierImage(plainInsuranceImage) {
        var self = this;
        
        self.ImageTypes = ko.observableArray(plainInsuranceImage.ImageTypes);
        self.ImageType = ko.observable(plainInsuranceImage.ImageType);        
    }
    
    function PatientInsuranceCarrierImageViewModel(items) {
        var self = this;
        
        self.PatientInsuranceCarrierImages = ko.observableArray(items);
        
        var innerImageTypes = JSON.parse('[{\"ID\":\"BackImage\",\"Name\":\"Back Image\"},{\"ID\":\"FrontImage\",\"Name\":\"Front Image\"},{\"ID\":\"Other\",\"Name\":\"Other\"}]');
        
        const newPatientInsuranceCarrierImage = {
            
            ImageType: "Other",
            ImageTypes: [],
        };

        for (let i = 0; i < innerImageTypes.length; i++) {
            newPatientInsuranceCarrierImage.ImageTypes.push(innerImageTypes[i]);
        }
        
         // Operations
   
        self.addpatientInsuranceCarrierImage = function() {
            self.PatientInsuranceCarrierImages.push(new PatientInsuranceCarrierImage(newPatientInsuranceCarrierImage));
        }
        
    }
    
    var plainImages = JSON.parse('[{\"ImageType\":\"Other\",\"ImageTypes\":[{\"ID\":\"BackImage\",\"Name\":\"Back Image\"},{\"ID\":\"FrontImage\",\"Name\":\"Front Image\"},{\"ID\":\"Other\",\"Name\":\"Other\"}]},{\"ImageType\":\"Other\",\"ImageTypes\":[{\"ID\":\"BackImage\",\"Name\":\"Back Image\"},{\"ID\":\"FrontImage\",\"Name\":\"Front Image\"},{\"ID\":\"Other\",\"Name\":\"Other\"}]},{\"ImageType\":\"Other\",\"ImageTypes\":[{\"ID\":\"BackImage\",\"Name\":\"Back Image\"},{\"ID\":\"FrontImage\",\"Name\":\"Front Image\"},{\"ID\":\"Other\",\"Name\":\"Other\"}]},{\"ImageType\":\"Other\",\"ImageTypes\":[{\"ID\":\"BackImage\",\"Name\":\"Back Image\"},{\"ID\":\"FrontImage\",\"Name\":\"Front Image\"},{\"ID\":\"Other\",\"Name\":\"Other\"}]}]');
    var patientInsuranceCarrierImagesViewModel = new PatientInsuranceCarrierImageViewModel(plainImages);
    ko.applyBindings(patientInsuranceCarrierImagesViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float: right; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 5px;">
           <a data-bind="click: addpatientInsuranceCarrierImage" href="#" class="button">Add New Image</a>
</div>
        
<table id="patientInsuranceImages" style="width: 100%;" class="alt1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th class="Table_Top" style="width: 80px;">
                    Back/Front 
                </th>        
            </tr>
        </thead>
         <!-- ko if: PatientInsuranceCarrierImages().length > 0 -->
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: PatientInsuranceCarrierImages">
            <tr>                
                <td>
                    <select 
                        data-bind="options: ImageTypes, value: ImageType, optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText:'Name'"
                        class="txtinput"
                        style="margin-top: 0px;"> 
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: ImageType, attr: {name: 'images[' + $index() + '].ImageType'}" />
                    <span data-bind="text: ImageType"></span>
                </td>                
            </tr>    
        </tbody>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of this line:

```
self.PatientInsuranceCarrierImages = ko.observableArray(items);
```

You are just putting array of items into observable array. That way your `ImageType` property in each item is not `observable` so Knockout does not track changes of it.
To fix this you need to map that `items` into collection of your defined objects at the top of your code snippet:

```
self.PatientInsuranceCarrierImages = ko.observableArray(items.map(i => new PatientInsuranceCarrierImage(i)));
```

```js
function PatientInsuranceCarrierImage(plainInsuranceImage) {
        var self = this;
        
        self.ImageTypes = ko.observableArray(plainInsuranceImage.ImageTypes);
        self.ImageType = ko.observable(plainInsuranceImage.ImageType);        
    }
    
    function PatientInsuranceCarrierImageViewModel(items) {
        var self = this;
        
        self.PatientInsuranceCarrierImages = ko.observableArray(items.map(i => new PatientInsuranceCarrierImage(i)));
        
        var innerImageTypes = JSON.parse('[{\"ID\":\"BackImage\",\"Name\":\"Back Image\"},{\"ID\":\"FrontImage\",\"Name\":\"Front Image\"},{\"ID\":\"Other\",\"Name\":\"Other\"}]');
        
        const newPatientInsuranceCarrierImage = {
            
            ImageType: "Other",
            ImageTypes: [],
        };

        for (let i = 0; i < innerImageTypes.length; i++) {
            newPatientInsuranceCarrierImage.ImageTypes.push(innerImageTypes[i]);
        }
        
         // Operations
   
        self.addpatientInsuranceCarrierImage = function() {
            self.PatientInsuranceCarrierImages.push(new PatientInsuranceCarrierImage(newPatientInsuranceCarrierImage));
        }
        
    }
    
    var plainImages = JSON.parse('[{\"ImageType\":\"Other\",\"ImageTypes\":[{\"ID\":\"BackImage\",\"Name\":\"Back Image\"},{\"ID\":\"FrontImage\",\"Name\":\"Front Image\"},{\"ID\":\"Other\",\"Name\":\"Other\"}]},{\"ImageType\":\"Other\",\"ImageTypes\":[{\"ID\":\"BackImage\",\"Name\":\"Back Image\"},{\"ID\":\"FrontImage\",\"Name\":\"Front Image\"},{\"ID\":\"Other\",\"Name\":\"Other\"}]},{\"ImageType\":\"Other\",\"ImageTypes\":[{\"ID\":\"BackImage\",\"Name\":\"Back Image\"},{\"ID\":\"FrontImage\",\"Name\":\"Front Image\"},{\"ID\":\"Other\",\"Name\":\"Other\"}]},{\"ImageType\":\"Other\",\"ImageTypes\":[{\"ID\":\"BackImage\",\"Name\":\"Back Image\"},{\"ID\":\"FrontImage\",\"Name\":\"Front Image\"},{\"ID\":\"Other\",\"Name\":\"Other\"}]}]');
    var patientInsuranceCarrierImagesViewModel = new PatientInsuranceCarrierImageViewModel(plainImages);
    ko.applyBindings(patientInsuranceCarrierImagesViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float: right; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 5px;">
           <a data-bind="click: addpatientInsuranceCarrierImage" href="#" class="button">Add New Image</a>
</div>
        
<table id="patientInsuranceImages" style="width: 100%;" class="alt1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th class="Table_Top" style="width: 80px;">
                    Back/Front 
                </th>        
            </tr>
        </thead>
         <!-- ko if: PatientInsuranceCarrierImages().length > 0 -->
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: PatientInsuranceCarrierImages">
            <tr>                
                <td>
                    <select 
                        data-bind="options: ImageTypes, value: ImageType, optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText:'Name'"
                        class="txtinput"
                        style="margin-top: 0px;"> 
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: ImageType, attr: {name: 'images[' + $index() + '].ImageType'}" />
                    <span data-bind="text: ImageType"></span>
                </td>                
            </tr>    
        </tbody>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </table>
```

Comment: thanks I have the same problem with a bidinghandlers can you please help me? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72942013/bindinghandlers-is-not-firing-with-knockout